# Capacitance to digital converter for moisture measurement

Tags: digital-logic, capacitance, converter, humidity

I'm currently working on a irrigation system for which I would like to build a low cost soil moisture sensor. I would like to measure the moisture levels of a given environment based on a capacitance.

[image]

So far I was unable to find a differential capacitance sensor (see fig.I)

I had a look at multiple touch sensors controller/button controller/you name it. They all had a ground plane and did not measure in differential mode. Does anybody know a differential capacitance sensor suitable for my purposes.

Note: Due to volume restrictions in my design, I am unable to use a sensor with a ground plane per measurement plane. Also, due to flexibility in the design (see fig. II) I can adjust the copper tube to match the capacity range of the sensor and can therefor not specify such a range.

Note 2: The copper tube inside the plastic tube should function as measurement pads. (see fig. II)

Comment: Seems this fixture bears *some* similarity to ECG methods, which are well-established. Perhaps the mid-electrode could be driven with an AC-probe signal with respect to a remote ground?

Comment: thanks, maybe there is. Im gonna have a look at those applications. However, I havent mentioned that i would like to use several more electrodes, maybe around 10 - 20 in total. Threrefore I do not want to add a ground electrode for ecery meassurement electrode.

Comment: what about a 555 mutlivibrator? it might be enough for the purpose. it can convert the capacity into frequency, which is easy to measure with a timer

Comment: This may be a possible solution. But I was looking for a more advanced approach with an IC which already offers some features and is accessible over I2C, SPI etc.